# Django Admin custom list_display name and ordering

Tags: django

I have the following AdminModel:

```
class ActionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'action_icon',
        'name_',
        'level',
        'class_',
        'category',
    )
    search_fields = ('name', 'category__name',)
    ordering = ('level', 'name', '_class')

    def name_(self, obj):
        return '<strong>%s</strong>' % (obj.name)

    def action_icon(self, obj):
        if obj.icon:
            return '<img title="%s" src="/media/%s" style="height: 42px; border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;" />' % (obj.name, obj.icon)
        else:
            return 'No Icon'

    def class_(self, obj):
        if obj == None:
            return '-'

        if obj._class:
            return '<img title="%s" src="/media/%s" style="height: 42px; border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;" />' % (obj._class.name, obj._class.icon)
        else:
            return obj._class

    def combo_action_(self, obj):
        if obj == None:
            return '-'

        if obj.combo_action != None:
            return '<img title="%s" src="/media/%s" style="height: 42px; border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;" />' % (obj.combo_action, obj.combo_action.icon)
        else:
            return obj.job

    # Allow HTML for these
    action_icon.allow_tags = True
    name_.allow_tags = True
    class_.allow_tags = True
    combo_action_.allow_tags = True

    # Allow ordering for these
    name_.admin_order_field = 'name'
    class_.admin_order_field = 'name'
```

Now I did allow ordering for the custom `name` and `class` field, yet the problem is that it will order by that what is returned with my custom methods (like `name_(self, obj)`).

How can I tell the AdminModel that I want to sort that field, but specifically on it's original field value, and not what I modified in the method?

Comment: AFAIK django does not let you order by custom methods / python values. You should be seeing DB ordering only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out; I named the reference tot he `_class` Model wrong;

Ordering should be:

```
ordering = ('level', '_class__name')
```

Order field should be:

```
class_.admin_order_field = '_class__name'
```